# How to include LaTeX with PStrick macros figure generated using Inkscape?

Tags: pstricks, svg, inkscape

I generated a  PStrick macros `.tex` file from a `.svg` using Inkscape 0.91 (`Shift+Ctr+S`, save as `LaTeX with PStrick macros`)  but I am not able to include it in my document I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \input{image.tex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But it seems that some packages is missing.
To try on your own if you don't want to install inkscape, you can save as a .tex file the following code, that I've generated using inkscape.

```
%LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
%%Creator: inkscape 0.91
%%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(744.09448819,1052.36220472)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 1}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(129.74527979,894.28571241)
\lineto(307.39757299,894.28571241)
\curveto(311.21360267,894.28571241)(314.2857132,891.21360188)(314.2857132,887.39757221)
\lineto(314.2857132,778.31671303)
\curveto(314.2857132,774.50068336)(311.21360267,771.42857283)(307.39757299,771.42857283)
\lineto(129.74527979,771.42857283)
\curveto(125.92925012,771.42857283)(122.85713959,774.50068336)(122.85713959,778.31671303)
\lineto(122.85713959,887.39757221)
\curveto(122.85713959,891.21360188)(125.92925012,894.28571241)(129.74527979,894.28571241)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 1}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(274.2857132,731.42858046)
\curveto(274.2857132,655.68667578)(207.76802226,594.2857297)(125.71429079,594.28572767)
\lineto(125.7142868,731.42858046)
\closepath
}
}
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: Please help us help you by turning your code into a minimal compilable example (i.e. with documentclass, packages, document environment) and specify how you are compiling.

Comment: As always ion this site, please post full minimal examples that others can copy and test as is. Then we don't have to guess. Plus we probably need the contents of `image.tex`

Comment: dflatex has only very limited support for pstricks, you could remove the `[pdf]` option aand use latex,dvips,ps2pdf rather than pdflatex, but of starting with svg, why not simply save as pdf and include that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot, but unfortunately it doesn't work.  Mainly I would like to have control over the text included in the image, that's why I usually use tikz.

Comment: you need to provide an example that people can use, and show the exact error message you get, if you just post code people can not run and say "it doesn't work" there isn't much help that can be given.

Comment: I suggest compiling your pstricks code as standalone with `xelatex`: you'll obtain a .pdf file with a tight bounding box,with the fonts you want, ready to be included.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, unfortunately, I can't add the original image I've generated a new one with inkscape following the procedure I wrote an posted the code. I was interested in the general problem more than my specific narrowed case... Thanks agian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \input{image.tex}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and run it with

```
pdflatex --shell-escape <file>
```

[image]

However: the PSTricks export from Inkscape is rubbish ...